# Creating Cookie/Session in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, cookies

I have two projects in the same tomcat and their URLs are different. One project is for services, another project is for front-end, user interface. When I create a cookie in services project, I can neither see nor get it in my browser when I enter URL of second project.

```
Cookie foo = new Cookie("foo", "bar");
foo.setMaxAge(1000);
foo.setPath("/");       
response.addCookie(foo);
```

Is it possible to create a global cookie (or session) for all projects in 
the same tomcat?